# Show notification in DragDrop method without maintaining sender's DoDragDrop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When showing a `MessageBox` (of an error) in a `DragDrop` event handler - the drag operation isn't yet completed and so when the cursor is over the desktop - it still has the drag icon. How do I prevent that?

To reproduce, simply drag a file into a Form with the following: (+`AllowDrop = true`)

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{            
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;//Doesn't help.
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never block a D+D event, it gums-up the drag source and makes it unresponsive.  Not getting the cursor restored is certainly a side-effect.  You'll need to run this kind of code *after* the event is completed.  Elegantly done by using Control.BeginInvoke().  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Error");
        }));
        base.OnDragDrop(drgevent);
    }
```

Do note that, in general, it should never get this far.  The drop attempt should have been veto-ed by your DragEnter event handler.  You could use, say, a StatusStrip to display a mild diagnostic, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why not to do this in the event handler (instead of overriding OnDragDrop)?

Comment: You can use an event handler if you want.  I'm firmly in the camp of programmers that don't think it makes sense for a class to listen to its own events.  Events are for code in other classes.